# React Native Wheel Color Picker - naeemur - Not sure how to actually access the color

Tags: javascript, react-native, colors

I'm trying to get the result of the colour picker so that I can constantly update the colour of a card in a separate component. The colour picker is for the colour of the card! I've tried a few things, but most come back as undefined or as an error. The issue is whate to put in `setCardColour()` I have `this.currentColor` but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

- This is the function for when the colour changes :

  ```js
  function changeCardColour() {
    setCardColour(this.currentColour)
    console.log(cardColour)
  }
  ```
- This is the Colour picker itself :

  ```html
  <ColourPicker
    color = {cardColour}
    swatches = {false}
    style = {styles.colourWheel}
    onColorChange = {changeCardColour}
  />
  ```
- [I would like the card to change colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RddXu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change code like,

```
function changeCardColour(selectedColour) {
  setCardColour(selectedColour)
}
```

According to doc,
`onColorChange: (color) => {}` callback function for slider and wheel thumb movement.

```
const RoundedColorPicker = () => {
  const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState('#000');

  const onColorChange = (selectedColor: string) => {
    setCurrentColor(selectedColor);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={RoundedColorPickerStyle.container}>
      <View
        style={[
          RoundedColorPickerStyle.currentColorContainer,
          {backgroundColor: currentColor},
        ]}
      />
      <Text>Current Color:{currentColor}</Text>
      <ColorPicker
        color={currentColor}
        swatchesOnly={false}
        onColorChange={onColorChange}
        thumbSize={40}
        sliderSize={40}
        noSnap={true}
        row={false}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

I use like this way and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! 
It doesn't seem to like being passed parameters. It doesn't recognise "color" or "this.color" in the brackets for the callback function.

Comment: Is there any chance that we could create an example of the colour wheel actually changing the colour of something?